# How to login website https://www.travelportroomsandmore.com/ automatically using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to login using the following source code. However, I can not login that website. Please help me. Thanks.

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->

<html>
<title>Autologin</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="login_form" name="login_form" method="post" action="https://www.travelportroomsandmore.com/login">
    <input id="sign_in_login" name="sign_in_login" type="text" value="Name" class="" />
    <input id="sign_in_password” name="sign_in_password" type="password" value="examplepassword"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="loginid" name="loginid"/>
                            </form>
<script>document.login_form.submit();</script>       
</body></html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: `id="sign_in_password”` should be `id="sign_in_password"`.

Comment: @ Marco Salerno @Xufox In this website [link](https://www.travelportroomsandmore.com/login), a login form is existed. I want to full fill my name and password at that website by using html and javascript without by hand. However, when I use the above source code( with id="sign_in_password"), the result is same when i enter https://www.travelportroomsandmore.com/search without login before. I expect, if the user and password is not correct, the result of using javascript and the result with the login by hand are same.

Answer (score -2):

```
    <!doctype html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->

<html>
<title>Autologin</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="login_form" name="login_form" method="post" action="https://www.travelportroomsandmore.com/login">
    <input id="sign_in_password" name="sign_in_login" type="text" value="Name" class="" />
    <input id="sign_in_password" name="sign_in_password" type="password" value="examplepassword"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="loginid" name="loginid"/>
                            </form>
<script>document.login_form.submit();</script>       
</body></html>
```

Comment: How does this help?  You haven't said what's different (if anything actually is), and it even has an error from the original post.

Comment: "sign_in_password” must be replaced by "sign_in_password". However, this is a https website. Therefore, I don't know how to login using html and javascript. @Archer